# Classloader-specific logging

Tags: java, logging, classloader

I have an application with a plugin-architecture similar to a Java EE application server, with a child-first classloader hierarchy.

There is a slight problem though. I would like to have a log file for each plugin. Or putting it another way, I would like to direct all logging performed in a classloader to its own file.

For the log calls that I have control over this is an easy thing to do. But when it comes to log calls that are performed by third-party libraries, I'm not sure how to go about this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just guessing: Maybe you could provide different resources to your third-party libs?

Comment: What do you mean by 'different resources'?

Comment: One thing classloaders do is providing resources. Just in case your libraries make use of this the classloaders could provide resources that setup the logging for example. I admit it sounds vague: If it doesn't make sense it doeesn't make sense... its just an idea...